# How does Python take in an expression as a parameter to a function?

Tags: python, performance, function, interpreter, python-idle

I am looking at a debilitating performance problem in Python while testing code out in the IDLE GUI.

For a recursive function:

```
def f(input1,input2):
    newinput1 = g(input1,input2);
    return f(newinput1,input2)
```

If I call the function f(20,A+10) where A is a constant then does each recursive call of f() get input2 = "A+10" as a string that is reinterpreted, get an expression that needs to be recalculated, or get a number that is the result of A+10 ?

I found this in the help file, but need something more well defined to understand:

"Abstractions tend to create indirections and force the interpreter to work more. If the levels of indirection outweigh the amount of useful work done, your program will be slower. You should avoid excessive abstraction, especially under the form of tiny functions or methods (which are also often detrimental to readability)."

What exactly is going on in Python?

Comment: Try writing down the recurrence with your example input.

Comment: @PhillipCloud: He's not "ranting about abstraction". That's a quote from something he read to try to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function as follows:

```
f(20, A+10)
```

Python evaluates `20` to `20` and `A+10` to whatever that works out to. Let's say `A` is currently `20`, so `A+10` works out to `30`. The names `input1` and `input2` are then bound to the values `20` and `30` in the environment of the call to `f`. Python will not need to reevaluate `A+10` when the value is used, and it will not record anything about how the value `30` was obtained. In particular, if you call

```
f(20, A)
```

`input2` will be bound to the current value of `A`, but it will not retain any ties to `A`. Reassigning `input2` inside `f` will not affect `A`.

Comment: Thanks, what if input2 is an optional parameter that is passed as f(20,input2=A+10) will this change anything?

Comment: @Jason: Nope. (Tangential note: If you define a function with a default value for an argument, the expression for the default value is only evaluated once, when the function is defined. This means that if the default value is a list, all calls that use the default value share a single list.)